# How can I find the IPFS URL for a CNFT.io asset?

Tags: nft, cnft.io, cardanoscan.io

I've tried several ways but couldn't find a relyable way to find the IPFS url for a CNFT.io asset.
I tried to find the policy id in https://pool.pm/tokens and in https://cardanoscan.io/. In the latter one I can find the policy id but not the right asset / token and even when I find it by manually searching for it, then I don't find the metadata for it that contains the IPFS URL. Is there a relyable way to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want to know.

For every asset on CNFT.io, there are three dots at the top right side.

1. Click on Cardanoscan option
2. It'll open cardanoscan with your token, i.e. https://cardanoscan.io/token/dcb16550b3831a9c675b5bd827ad0ffced2dc0310b0d839c5c1dcd5e.CuteDudes3472
3. Go to *Mint Transactions* tab and click on the transaction.
4. It'll open the transaction in cardanoscan, i.e. https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/35c1c8fb3da4a6a23476b2d05288ae2314468b92e4fb6c87e8801590689f85e7?tab=tokenmint
5. Go to *Metadata* tab and click on label *721*
6. There should be displayed the metadata of the NFT, including URL to the image or files.

Comment: "For every asset on CNFT.io, there are three dots at the top right side...".
Argh. That was the simple solution that I missed :facepalm:
I tried to find it using the policy id and the asset id. Thanks a lot!